# Whether map’s iterator could add shared_ptr's counts?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

For example:

```
#include <memory>

shared_ptr<map<int, int>> ptr1 = make_shared<map<int, int>>();
map<int, int>::const_iterator iter = ptr1->begin();
shared_ptr<map<int, int>> ptr2 = make_shared<map<int, int>>();
ptr1 = ptr2;
```

My question: Could the iter add the counts of ptr1?  In this case, will the ptr1's memory address free after ptr1 = ptr2?

Comment: No, it could not. In your example, both `ptr1` and `ptr2` would end up pointing to the second map. The first map will be destroyed; `iter` will become invalid.

Comment: Egon Spengler: Don't cross the maps.
Peter Venkman: Why?
Egon Spengler: It would be bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot.

When `ptr1=ptr2` runs, the last shared pointer to the first map is gone and the object is destroyed.

`iter` is now invalid, and almost any use besides destruction or assigning over it results in undefined behavior.

Creating an iterator that makes its container persist is possible, if quite intrusive.  As a general rule, you should instead learn to keep object lifetime simple and work with object lifetime, not expect smart pointers to solve it for you.